# why reference error occurs when do circular dependency between commonjs module and es6 module?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, commonjs, es6-modules

I am reading this [article](https://hackernoon.com/node-js-tc-39-and-modules-a1118aecf95e), and it illusrates two cases:

**case 1:**

[image]

A:

```
import {log} from "B"
export default function() {
  log('hello world')
}
```

B

```
module.exports.log = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}
```

case 2:

[image]

A:

```
const b = require('B')
exports.b = b.foo()
exports.a = 1
```

B:

```
import {a} from "A"
export const foo () => a
```

For the **case1**, it says

> When the code for “A” is parsed, and the Module Record is created, it would detect that “B” is not an ESM, so the validation step that verifies that log is exported by “B” would be pending.

and for **case2**, it says

> This type of cycle becomes largely impossible to fulfill because when the ESM “B” is linked and evaluated, the symbol “a” has not yet been defined and exported by CommonJS module “A”. This type of case would likely have to be treated as a reference error.

**So my question is**: why in case1 "the validation step" "would be pending", but not case2?? for me, both are ES module that references a named export in commonjs module, why case1 can be put into pending but case2 will throw referenceerror.